# Empty deque versus unused pointer to deque

Tags: c++, deque

I have a class that sometimes needs to use a member of type `deque<int>` if an argument is passed to the constructor, and if it isn't, the member will not be used. What is the best way to deal with this situation efficiently and stylistically?

I'd like to also mention that objects of this class should be able to be passed to the same function, though removing the ability for storage in the same container is fine. I have never done polymorphism (as hinted at in the comments), but I think I am going to read about it and try it out.

My two ideas:
- Keep the member variable as a `deque<int>`, which will be stored as an empty `deque<int>` I assume.
- Use a pointer to a `deque<int>`, only calling `new` if it is needed.

Comment: Unless you're making tons of these, keep things simple.  Don't optimize before you have requirements.  Making sure the code works and is easily understandable is the most important thing.  In other words, just make it and don't use it if you don't need it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is a simple class created potentially tens of millions of times in other classes I am writing.

Comment: I also like having beautiful code :)

Comment: First find out `sizeof(std::deque<int>)` and look at the assembly generated with optimizations on to just construct and destroy an empty `deque`.  You may be surprised.

Comment: Hmm. "if an argument is passed to the constructor"... if you know when creating each object whether or not the object will ever need the `deque`, this might be a job for polymorphism.

Comment: the beauty is in the simplicity.  That means avoiding special cases where ever possible.  Focussing on perceived beauty unrelated to maintainability or functionality is an immature approach to programming and leads to unmaintainable programs that tend to fail once you get past programs that are more than trivial complexity.

Comment: Depending on what you do with the objects of your class, using a template may be a solution. The effect would be that objects-with-deque and objects-without-deque would formally be different data types, so you would e.g. have difficulties putting instances of both types into the same container.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the pointer to the deque member when initializing it for use:

```
deque<int> queue_;
deque<int> *ptr_;

ptr_(NULL); // not used

ptr_(&queue_);
```

However, speed wise, if you most often do not use the queue, the new is likely going to be faster since by default all you'd do it set a NULL in a pointer. If it is used 50/50, then my method is probably one of the fastest because you do not need to handle more heap.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue,I would probably use option 1 along with a "is_initialized" boolean flag:

```
class A
{
  bool is_initialized;    
  public:
     A(bool used=false):is_initialized(used)  
     {
     }; 
  private:
     deque<int> _d;
};
```

Yes, you may be able to save a little bit of memory with option 2 when deque is not used, but if it is used you incur an overhead of dereferencing a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is exactly [`boost::optional<deque<int>>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).  Nothing else documents your intention more clearly and correctly here.